# Manipulate evaluation sequence

Tags: evaluation, manipulate

`Manipulate` doesn't always evaluate in the order I expect it to. What is the evaluation sequence for `Manipulate` and other functions involved with the front end? I have seen the evaluation sequence for kernel only functions, but that was for a reference for Mathematica 3, and doesn't deal with the front end.

Comment: Can you provide an example of Manipulate not evaluating in a certain sequence?

Comment: Using the initialization option, it will evaluate the variables for the controls, then the initialization and then the content. The question is more focused on what is the actual evaluation sequence though.

Comment: Well you seem to have answered your own question then.

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping for. I'll see if I can find the one for the kernel tomorrow to better explain.

Comment: I'd love to help more, I'm just curious as to what you're expecting. If you give us an example we can maybe piece together why it evaluates in the order it does.

Comment: This SO post (especially the answers) might be useful here: [Print Dynamic variable inside DynamicModule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730863/print-dynamic-variable-inside-dynamicmodule)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to my previous experiences and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730863/print-dynamic-variable-inside-dynamicmodule) post, the sequence goes like this (please feel free to correct me in this post):

1. From the documentation:

   > `Manipulate` generates a `DynamicModule` object, with the variables `u`, `v`, etc. specified as local.

   That is, first Manipulate wraps its **result** into `DynamicModule`, then...
2. ...gives **unique names** to local variables (as it is a scoping construct).
3. Next, the body of `Manipulate` is evaluated in standard order.
4. The output cell is created by evaluating the result of the `DynamicModule` (or the `Manipulate`).
5. If there was any `Initialization :> init` inside `Manipulate`, it is now evaluated "when the result is first displayed in a particular session".
6. If there is any `Deinitialization :> deinit` inside `Manipulate` **and** the dynamic output cannot be displayed any more, `deinit` is evaluated.

Contraintuitively, `Initialization` is called almost ultimately which caused me some frustration over time.

To understand how to load a package with your dynamic content by `Needs`, see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4253/89).