# What is the proper method to load a Mathematica package inside a DynamicModule

Tags: programming, dynamic, manipulate, packages

I have a `DynamicModule` that requires loading of Mathematica packages.  The usual methods do not seem to apply (`` Needs["MathematicaPackage`"]] ``, etc) I've tried

```
Dynamic[Initialization :> (Needs["Package`"])];
```

with only partial success.

I'm sure this is done regularly, but cannot find any MMA documentation to that effect.
What's the best way to load Mathematica packages in `Dynamic` or `DynamicModule` and `Manipulate`?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what “with only partial success” means? What happened, what is your issue?

Comment: Certainly!  Initial results provided package errors using Needs, and it was easy to see the package was not used in the module.  Now the errors are related to LibraryFunction::cfta: Argument {{bla,bla,bla},<<44>> at position 2 should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers. >> and only a single package loading error followed by the usual list errors related to the package functions that did not load. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Possibly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/595/is-it-possible-to-use-begin-and-end-inside-a-manipulate

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Not exactly, but thank's for the suggestion. Just wrestling with some of the newer Dynamic functionality and breaking things nicely by trial and error. ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While `Initialization` is a useful option, it is only evaluated when the body of the `DynamicModule` is displayed on screen. See some explanation on the evaluation sequence [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153/89).

### With DynamicModule

I've constructed a `` TestPackage` `` for this case, it contains the globally exported variable `$Test`, with a value of 123. The following example shows that the package is not loaded (note that you have to clear dynamic content and variables (e.g. restart kernel) for each example below to start from a clear state of memory):

```
DynamicModule[{}, $Test, Initialization :> (Needs["TestPackage`"])]
```

> `$Test`

It doesn't work with an explicit `` TestPackage`$Test `` call either indicating that `$Test` (and thus the body) is evaluated **before** the `Initialization` code. This is somewhat contraintuitive, as one expects the initialization code to be evaluated before anything else. I should note here that the package **is** loaded, it is just loaded too late. Any later cells calling for `$Test` return the correct value though. One way to overcome this in the given setup is to use the explicit name of `$Test` in a dynamic output, which updates the unrecognized `$Test` output when the package is finally loaded during evaluation:

```
DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[TestPackage`$Test], Initialization :> Needs["TestPackage`"])]
```

> `123`

The second example is even more strange. While the package loading code is included in the body, `$Test` is still not recognized:

```
DynamicModule[{}, Needs["TestPackage`"]; $Test]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using the explicit name of the variable helps here, indicating that parsing (done before evaluation) causes `$Test` to be a local variable that is not recognized as `` TestPackage`$Test ``:

```
DynamicModule[{}, Needs["TestPackage`"]; TestPackage`$Test]
```

> `123`

Of course the easiest way is:

```
Needs["TestPackage`"];
DynamicModule[{}, $Test]
```

> `123`

**Update**

And the Wolfram way is (see [this conference material](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7977/UserInterfaceProgramming.cdf?file_id=7566)):

> "Can be solved by two `Needs[]` statements...one to fulfill <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
>   evaluation and one to fulfill `Dynamic` evaluation. Note that this is
>   only an issue because of `$ContextPath`. Any other initialization code
>   could have safely appeared one time inside of `Initialization`."

```
Needs["TestPackage`"]; 
DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[$Test], Initialization :> Needs["TestPackage`"])]
```

> `123`

### With Manipulate

Following the Wolfram way, one needs the outer package loading, but in `Manipulate`, `SaveDefinitions` works correctly grabbing the definition of `$Test` from the package:

```
Needs["TestPackage`"];
Manipulate[$Test, {$Test, None}, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

> `123`

### With Dynamic

According to the above examples, with `Dynamic` (each cell should be evaluated in a fresh kernel):

```
Dynamic[$Test, Initialization :> (Needs["TestPackage`"])]
```

> `` Global`$Test ``

```
Dynamic[TestPackage`$Test, Initialization :> (Needs["TestPackage`"])]
```

> `123`

```
Dynamic[Needs["TestPackage`"]; $Test]
```

> `` Global`$Test ``

```
Dynamic[Needs["TestPackage`"]; TestPackage`$Test]
```

> `123`

Comment: Thanks very much @István Zachar!  This is an excellent and thorough explanation!

Comment: @RHall And I myself have made some useful discoveries during this fieldtrip :)