# Not able to load the package in CDF

Tags: packages, cdf-format, initialization

I am facing a problem in loading the package. My code is working in `Mathematica` but after deploying it into `CDF`, it is unable to load the package and shows error.

The code was not even working in `Mathematica` when I evaluated it for the first time but when I evaluated it one more time it worked.

I got help from this [stackexchange question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/what-is-the-proper-method-to-load-a-mathematica-package-inside-a-dynamicmodule)

And now it is working in Notebook but not in `CDF`, after relaunching the Mathematica Kernel.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, three things are needed:

- Explicitly list the contexts of the functions that are in the package. For example, if you are using the function f in package test call it test`f[] instead of just f[].
- Call Needs on the package inside the initialization option for the Manipulate that makes up your CDF. I would recommend calling needs with the syntax that gives the full file path to the package. For example:  `Initialization->{Needs["Plambda`","filepathhere"]}`
- Place the package inside the installation directory for CDFPlayer under AddOns\Applications. For example under windows:

  > ```
  > C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Wolfram CDF
  > Player\8.0\AddOns\Applications
  > ```

My honest recommendation is that you create a simple example package and CDF and try to get this to work before getting a real world example working. The example will be much easier to debug and think about.