# How to open hyperlinks (from web-embedded CDF) in a new tab

Tags: cdf-format

I have a problem with `Hyperlink` (in a web-embedded CDF) opening links in the same browser tab and I couldn't find an option to avoid that.

I have the following constraints:

1. CDF is web-embedded (created by me).
2. The hyperlink should open only after mouse clicking, no combinations with keyboard keys are allowed.

**Failed attempts:**

- I've tried to click it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> like it is written in `Help` but it does not work. It doesn't matter because of constraint #2 above. However if it is possible to mimic the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key being pressed (in some other way than pressing the key) maybe that will help?
- I've tried to replace `Hyperlink` by `Button[ "link", SystemOpen["link"]]` but there is no reaction.

I don't think this is important, but this is how I'm testing it:

- I create a CDF file using *Mathematica*
- Export as "web embeddable..."
- I paste script received in the end to a `.txt` file -> save -> switch to `.html`

It is quite important for me to find a solution to this, because the CDF resets every time the link opens in the same tab.

Comment: Can't you allow only the `Shift` key to be pressed and ignore key presses from all other keys?

Comment: @rm -rf It is not the case. I do not want any keys to participate :)

Comment: Moreover, Shift does not work in web-embedded CDF! Only CRTL, but it is related to browser not due to CDF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I probably have an idea how to turn a `Button` into want you require with the help of `` JLink` ``. The trick includes to use the java methods to open a link in the system browser. The following is a small working example without catching any exceptions and testing whether opening an URL is even supported.

If I export this `Manipulate` as an embedded CDF, open it and click the button, on OSX a new tab is opened every time.

```
Manipulate[
 Button["Browse Me", desktop@browse[uri]],
 Initialization :> (Needs["JLink`"]; InstallJava[]; 
   LoadJavaClass["java.awt.Desktop"];
   desktop = java`awt`Desktop`getDesktop[]; 
   uri = JavaNew["java.net.URI", 
     "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com"]),
 SaveDefinitions -> True
]
```

### Comment to *comments*

> That definitely works, thank You. I'm not very familiar with Java so let me ask You some questions. I've checked those procedures and it seems there is no direct question to Java about new tab. Is it then 'nature' of JavaNew[]?, or lucky coincidence?

The *Mathematica* function `JavaNew` has nothing to do with opening something in a *new* tab. It is just java code transformed into a *Mathematica* call. The `uri = JavaNew[...]` line is equivalent to the following java syntax

```java
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI("http://mathematica.stackexchange.com");
```

which creates a new `URI` object which is then opened in the browser. Basically, I only transformed the following java function into *Mathematica* call with the help of `` JLink` ``:

```java
public void openUrl(String url) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
  if(java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ) {
        java.awt.Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();

        if(desktop.isSupported(java.awt.Desktop.Action.BROWSE) ) {
          java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI(url);
              desktop.browse(uri);
        }
      }
}
```

To answer your question: `desktop.browser(url)` seems to open everything in a new tab and yes, this is a lucky coincidence to make this solution so short. But you should not completely ignore Alberts concerns; while this seems to work on many machines, there *is* the probability that on some machines it won't.

Comment: That definitely works, thank You. I'm not very familiar with `Java` so let me ask You some questions. I've checked those procedures and it seems there is no direct question to `Java` about new tab. Is it then 'nature' of `JavaNew[]`?, or lucky coincidence?

Comment: @Kuba: what this does it to make use of OS functionality accessed via Java (see e.g. [awt dektop doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)). It uses the default browser to open an URI. **When** the CDF runs in the default browser and the configuration allows it that might work as desired (open in a new tab). It didn't work for my setup (firefox on Windows) out of the box and whether it works will depend on many details of OS, browser and configuration. With all the security measures in todays browsers I think you can't expect this to work in general...

Comment: @AlbertRetey It works nicely for me on Windows even when the CDF is not run in the default browser, though it always opens a new tab in the default browser, but that should be acceptable.

Comment: @halirutan +1 Yet another example that [this list](http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html) is not quite correct. JLink does work in FreeCDF.

Comment: @RolfMertig: What I tried to make clear is that while it might work in many cases, you can't guarantee it will. An extreme case is users who might have uninstalled or deleted the executable  that their OS still is configured to use as default browser. But I could well imagine that also the fact that browsers and plugins run in sandboxes these days might well result in this not working in some cases. As I said it didn't work for me but I'm sure I could get it working if I wanted by tweaking my setup...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I share your concerns, although I believe that *Mathematica* uses java under the hood to make `Hyperlinks` work. Even Wolfram can't do anything if there isn't any browser installed.

Comment: @halirutan: having deleted the configured default browser was an extreme example and it certainly isn't WRIs fault if this won't work, and also not Oracles, btw. I just wanted to emphasize that even for a correct setup (I consider my setup to be working but probably more secure than necessary) it might fail. If you provide a CDF for others to use, they might be dissapointed if such a button doesn't work and that's not very unlikely. If you're mainly using this for your own use and it works, then there is of course no problem...

Comment: @halirutan: I probably should add that I don't think that there is a bulletproof method to do what the OP asked for, so your solution very well could be the best possible. If you view the CDF in one browser (e.g. chrome for me), that code will most probably open a new window/tab of the default browser (firefox for me). It is also up to the browser whether it will open a new window or a new tab when asked to open an URL by the OS. Finally it is a common security measure to inhibit undesired access of browsers and plugin code to OS functionality, and this method could well be affected by that.

Comment: @AlbertRetey and Rolf Mertig, Thank You for those remarks. @halirutan I'll award this answer this evening. I just want to wait in case someone has answer not based on `Need`. I do not have reputation for many answers :)

Answer (score 1):

halirutan have given me good answer. It works :)

My cdf is not based on `Manipulate` but  `DynamicModule` so I had to add small thing to make it work :) That was fast thanks to Istvan Zachar [work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/what-is-the-proper-method-to-load-a-mathematica-package-inside-a-dynamicmodule).

Following code is usefull since simple switching `Manipulate` to `DynamicModule` is not enough. The only differece is with using explicit names:

```
DynamicModule[{},
Button["Browse Me", desktop@browse[uri]], 
Initialization :> (
  Needs["JLink`"];
  JLink`InstallJava[];
  JLink`LoadJavaClass["java.awt.Desktop"];
  desktop = java`awt`Desktop`getDesktop[];
  uri = JLink`JavaNew["java.net.URI","http://mathematica.stackexchange.com"]
)]
```

From what I've checked this and halirutan versions works on WinXP and Win7 with Chrome.