# Creating a Mathematica executable that uses JLink

Tags: export, java

I am making a program in Mathematica that uses the Robot class of Java and some other Mathematica functions. I want the end product to be a standalone executable that can run even if a computer does not have Mathematica. Is this possible, and how so? Would CDFPlayer work, or is there some other way?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with FreeCDF, others will tell you if it's possible using Enterprise CDF ...

Comment: IF the Mathematica functions you want to use can compile, you might have a shot at this as a standalone executable.  You can likely rig up something with PlayerPro, Enterprise CDF, or WebMathematica.  I'd wager that most attempts to do this have ended sadly.

Comment: I don't really see the point why you ask a question. You **know** you want to use ``JLink` `` and a CDF, why haven't you just tried to create a minimal example? Look for instance [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25910/187) where I demonstrate how to create a `JLink` button with FreeCDF. Go and try something similar with your `Robots` class.