# Stopping Evaluation of Manipulate after it goes through once

Tags: manipulate

I do quite a bit of textual analysis with *Mathematica*, and am currently making some `Manipulate` objects to walk people through key terms in the database.

One issue I am running into with `Manipulate` however is that it continues to evaluate. For example, please consider the following code: (**warning, this code does loop FWIW**)

```
testInput = {{"the", 4415}, {"of", 1284}, {"and", 1608}, {"in", 
    1384}, {"to", 1353}, {"a", 1205}, {"coal", 815}, {"was", 
    753}, {"by", 459}, {"were", 449}, {"for", 382}, {"is", 
    362}, {"with", 324}, {"from", 322}, {"on", 317}, {"that", 
    311}, {"as", 302}, {"mines", 264}, {"s", 257}, {"mining", 
    257}, {"it", 253}, {"this", 244}, {"at", 244}, {"be", 
    225}, {"cape", 216}};

testInput2 = {{"the", 4415}, {"of", 1284}, {"and", 1608}, {"in", 
    1384}, {"to", 1353}, {"a", 1205}, {"coal", 815}, {"was", 
    753}, {"by", 459}, {"were", 449}, {"for", 382}, {"is", 
    362}, {"with", 324}, {"from", 322}, {"on", 317}, {"that", 
    311}, {"as", 302}, {"mines", 264}, {"s", 257}, {"mining", 
    257}, {"it", 253}, {"this", 244}, {"at", 244}, {"be", 
    225}, {"cape", 216}};

files = {testInput, testInput2};

Manipulate[
 viewerCount1 = {};
 Do[
  input = access;
  AppendTo[viewerCount1, 
   If[Length[Flatten[Cases[input, {word1, _}]]] == 0, 0, 
    Flatten[Cases[input, {word1, _}]][[2]]]];
  , {access, files}];
 Print[viewerCount1];
 , {{word1, "the", "First Word:"}}]
```

It goes through, runs the `Do` loop which picks out the word frequencies of `word1' in the sample text provided.

But then, it **continues to loop**. It goes back through and does it again. And again. And again. This is all without any change to the `Manipulate` input.

Is there a way to get to the end of the line `Print[viewerCount1]` and then **stop** until the input changes?

I have tried to figure out the behaviour by looking elsewhere, such as ["Manipulate Evaluation Sequence"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113/manipulate-evaluation-sequence) and in the documentation, but there seems to be a paucity of textual examples like this.

Comment: Would you please give a *minimal* example which shows that behaviour (and which ideally does not depend on having a certain directory or certain files)?

Comment: @celtschk Just trying to do so now.

Comment: @celtschk Its updated now. Thank you and hope that this is clearer.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want to achieve but does adding `TrackedSymbols->{word1}` to `Manipulate` help?

Comment: @sebhofer It does. Do you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: I guess @celtschk beat me to the answer... and I have nothing to add to that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a minimal example also showing that effect:

```
Manipulate[v=0; v++; Print[v], {i, 1}]
```

The problem is that `Manipulate` by default does not only track `i`, but also `v`. So when `v` is changed inside the `Manipulate`, it triggers a re-evaluation. Since the re-evaluation again modifies `v`, it triggers another re-evaluation, and so on.

There are two possible ways out. The first is:

```
Manipulate[Module[{v=0}, v++; Print[v]], {i, 1}]
```

That way, `v` is localized and not tracked by `Manipulate`. This is probably the best solution for your case, because after all you don't want any other code outside your `Manipulate` to interfere with that calculation.

The second is:

```
Manipulate[v=0; v++; Print[v], {i, 1}, TrackedSymbols :> {i}]
```

Here, you explicitly tell `Manipulate` to only track `i`, not `v`.

In your original code, it's the `AppendTo` which triggers the re-evaluation.

Comment: And to the readers: the `RuleDelayed` (:>) is quite necessary here. I forget this time after time.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries @celtschk Since `RuleDelayed` and this answer have both really gotten me over a hump in my work and have helped me understand the behaviour of my programs (which were sucking resources/occasionally crashing before), just a sincere thanks to both of you!

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: What is the significance of `RuleDelayed` here?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It's to prevent that a value is being passed as an option value instead of the symbol what's needed here. Rule can work sometimes when the variable hasn't got a value yet but it is dangerous.