# For[] or While[] can't be used inside Manipulate[]?

Tags: manipulate

Here is a code sample that creates a control object which calculates the expressions inside `Maniplate` again and again and never stop (it's proved by the code in the note):

*Sample 1:*

```
Manipulate[date = Table[0, {num}];
 For[i = 1, i <= num, i++, date[[i]] = Sin[i]];(*Print@i;*)
 ListPlot[{date}], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

`While` has the same problem:

*Sample 2:*

```
Manipulate[date = Table[0, {num}]; i = 1;
 While[i <= num, date[[i]] = Sin[i]; i++];
 ListPlot[{date}], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

I know if I choose `Do`, the problem will no longer exist:

*Sample 3:*

```
Manipulate[date = Table[0, {num}];
 Do[date[[i]] = Sin[i], {i, 1, num}];
 ListPlot[{date}], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

Still, I know I can solve the problem if I throw the expression into `Module` if what I'm using is `For`:

*Sample 4:*

```
Manipulate[Module[{i}, date = Table[0, {num}];
  For[i = 1, i <= num, i++, date[[i]] = Sin[i]];
  ListPlot[{date}]], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

And…yeah, it doesn't work for the code above with `While`…:

*Sample 5:*

```
Manipulate[Module[{j}, date = Table[0, {num}]; j = 1;
  While[j <= num, date[[j]] = Sin[j]; j++];
  ListPlot[{date}]], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}]
(*This still creates a problematic control object*)
```

How to solve the problem with `While`? what actually happens inside `Manipulate`? what's the exact reason for the endless loop?

---

OK, the problem with *sample 5* turns out to be a collaboration of *Sample 4* and *Sample 5*, before I run sample 5, a control object has been already created by *Sample 4* (let's call it *Object 4* below, and so we have *Object 5* for *Sample 5*).I think the process should be like this: when `date = Table[0, {num}];` in *Sample 5* is executed, it's tracked by *Object 4*, and then `For[i = 1, i <= num, i++, date[[i]] = Sin[i]];` in *Sample 4* is executed, so it is tracked by *Object 5*…so this story tells us how important a good programing habit is…

Comment: Might be similar to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/stopping-evaluation-of-manipulate-after-it-goes-through-once?rq=1)

Comment: @cormullion Yeah, quite similar and the solution with `TrackedSymbols:>` in your link works! But I still wonder why the solution with `Module` doesn't work for `While`…

Comment: @xzczd: why do you say that it wouldn't work for `While`? For me it does: `Manipulate[Module[{i = 1},
  date = Table[0, {num}];
  While[i <= num, date[[i]] = Sin[i]; i++];
  ListPlot[{date}]], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}]` won't result in an endless loop...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Oh, I should have add the sample…in fact my `i=1` is set in the expressions:`Manipulate[Module[{j}, date = Table[0, {num}]; j = 1;
  While[j <= num, date[[j]] = Sin[j]; j++];
  ListPlot[{date}]], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}]`

Comment: @xzczd: just tried this one, doesn't loop endless for me either (8.0.4 on Windows 7 64bit). Which version are you using? Are you sure you didn't got fooled by another `Manipulate` shown at the same time?

Comment: @AlbertRetey ……You get the truth, I've added the conclusion to the question. OK, this time question is completely solved :D.

Comment: @xzczd: the problem which shows when two manipulates are showing is relativeley easy to understand and resolve. On the other hand it's still not entirely clear why some of the mainpulates will loop endlessly while others don't: I believe that it has to do with some heuristics with which `Manipulates` tries to resolve the dependencies and generate a good automatic tracking. This seems to recognize that the assignments to `date` within a scoping construct shouldn't trigger an update while it doesn't recognize the same thing when the assignments are not within a scoping construct...

Comment: ... To my understanding that's not something that can be understood from the language or is documented anywhere but rather a matter of how those heuristics are implemented -- and as these seem to not be fully documented (more precisely: I haven't found such a documentation) they might even change between versions. Note that I don't feel like I'm on firm ground with these speculations and could be completely wrong :-).

Comment: looks like I'm really wrong and Nasser already pointed out the right thing: for whatever reason it's only the reassignments of a global `i` that cause the endless loops, the reassignments of `date` seem to be recognized as not worth tracking even without a scoping construct. I still think that my statements about these things being a matter of how the internal heuristics are implemented might be correct...

Comment: @AlbertRetey ? You mean that the `date` isn't tracked in any case in your last comment? Then how to explain the behaviour of _Object 4_ and _Object 5_? Also, I observed the case that the endless loop won't appear if _Object 4_ and _Object 5_ are not shown up in the notebook concurrently, I mean we should drag the scrollbar and let at least part of the Object be seen, or the loop won't happen, is this what you found?

Comment: @xzczd: No, I think `date` is tracked. See my answer for more details about the difference between the tracking of `i` and `date`, I hope that makes more clear where I think there is still something that hasn't been explained (and most probably can only be explained by someone knowing the internal implementation...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not tell `Manipulate` which symbols to track, the default is `Full`

[image]

Hence use `TrackedSymbols` to explicitly tell it which symbols to track

```
Manipulate[
 date = Table[0, {num}]; i = 1;
 While[i <= num, date[[i]] = Sin[i]; i++];
 ListPlot[{date}],
 {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1},
 TrackedSymbols :> {num}
 ]
```

Another solution is to use `Module`, and add `i` and `date` as the local symbols to the internal module. Now Manipulate will not track these as they are not its own symbols.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{date, i},
  date = Table[0, {num}]; i = 1;
  While[i <= num, date[[i]] = Sin[i]; i++];
  ListPlot[{date}]
  ],
 {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot `date`!…But in the sample with `For`, it still works fine though I only add `i` as the local symbol, why?

Comment: Hehe, yeah, that's a good resource, and as I said in the comment below, this question is more for curiosity :D, and, I've added the most puzzled code to my question: that's indeed a sample that can't be solved without adding both `i` and `date` as the local symbols.

Comment: Albert found the truth for `While`…see my edit for the question for more details.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve the desired result more succinctly, without the need for the procedural `For` or `While` or `Do` which are rarely used in Mathematica, by using the functional programming features and built in list comprehension of functions such as `Sin`.

The functional style often removes completely the need for local or global variables to hold results for other pieces of code to work on.

It does this by wrapping layers of functions, like a coding onion, around the the key pieces of data, in this case the number of points you want to plot, `num`. Each function then works on the return value of the enclosed function.

The benefits of this are more concise code and fewer bugs because there is no "state", in the code which can become polluted by other parts of the code.

```
   Manipulate[ListPlot[Sin[Range[num]]], {num, 2, 20}]
```

Or even more concisely:

```
   Manipulate[ListPlot@Sin@Range@num, {num, 2, 20}]
```

where the code begins to read like a simple list of things to do `num` rather than a multi-line coding structure like `For` etc.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, I know, in fact the original question isn't raised by me but I found myself unable to tell the exact reason for the problem so I turn to here…still thanks for your vivid explain for the functional programming feature of Mma!

Comment: No problem, I hope the onion didn't bring tears to your eyes :)

Answer (score 3):

Nasser has given two perfect solutions to the original problem. But there is still an open question: Why is there an infinite loop in some cases but not the others. I don't have an answer to that and this answer will just show how to test the different behaviour of the various cases.

As I have noted in one of the comments, there is an obvious problem if you show more than one of the following `Manipulate`s at the same time. This is due to the global symbols used and relatively easy to understand: the change of e.g. the global `date` in one of the `Manipulate` will cause the other `Manipulate` to update which will change `date` again and cause the first to update and so on. For that reason, it is definitely a good idea to localize all variables within a `Manipulate`, which also would have solved the original problem in the first place (see Nassers second solution)...

Despite of that solution, it's still somewhat unclear when indefinite loops occur and when not. Let me start with the original `Manipulate`, where I have added a `PlotLabel` so we can easily see when an update occurs:

```
Manipulate[date = Table[0, {num}]; i = 1;
 While[i <= num, date[[i]] = Sin[i]; i++];
 ListPlot[{date}, PlotLabel -> DateString[]], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}]
```

when evaluating it, it is obvious that the redefinitions of the global symbols in its body cause it to permanently update. We now know how to solve it (make sure to delete the output of the first before trying this):

```
Manipulate[date = Table[0, {num}]; i = 1;
 While[i <= num, date[[i]] = Sin[i]; i++];
 ListPlot[{date}, PlotLabel -> DateString[]], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {num}]
```

This will now only update when `num` is changed -- which is what we usually want. Note that even if we redefine e.g. `date={}`, the `Manipulate` won't update as the tracking of `date` is suppressed. Of course we can also track `date` (but not `i`), as here:

```
Manipulate[date = Table[0, {num}]; i = 1;
 While[i <= num, date[[i]] = Sin[i]; i++];
 ListPlot[{date}, PlotLabel -> DateString[]], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {num, date}]
```

This will now update when you do e.g. `date={}` (date will be redefined when the body of the `Manipulate` is evaluated so the plot will be the same, but you'll see the `PlotLabel` change). But also note that this doesn't cause an infinite loop, although the global symbol `date` is redefined within the body (and `num+1` times, to be precise).

On the other hand, if we track `i` but not `date`, this causes an infinite loop (again, make sure to delete all the other outputs to exclude the mentioned problem):

```
Manipulate[date = Table[0, {num}]; i = 1;
 While[i <= num, date[[i]] = Sin[i]; i++];
 ListPlot[{date}, PlotLabel -> DateString[]], {{num, 2}, 1, 20, 1}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {num, i}]
```

Why the tracking of `i` causes the infinite loop but that of `date` doesn't isn't something that I think can be understood from how the language works but seems to be detail of how the updating is internally implemented.

Of course the best solution is to localize all variables. There are cases where it isn't possible to work entirely with variables which are local within the most inner enclosing `Dynamic` or `Manipulate`. For these cases the correct automatic detection of when updates are necessary and when not seems to be difficult and doesn't always work as "expected". So it is, especially for larger graphical interfaces, often necessary to set the `TrackedSymbols` explicitly. I think that's something everyone working on anything but the most trivial `Manipulate`s should be aware of...