# Manual CellGrouping option causes crash at cell evaluation

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, bugs

**Update: Try to reproduce this behaviour with [`CellGrouping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellGrouping.html) set to manual**. To do that:

- either evaluate `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CellGrouping -> Manual]`,
- or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to bring up the **Option Inspector** window, **Lookup** (among **Global preferences**) the option `CellGrouping` and set it to `Manual`.

Please test whether the phenomen is reproducible for you with the changed setting. You can reset cell grouping to its default behaviour by:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CellGrouping -> Automatic]
```

---

Strangest bug ever. Copy the following piece of code to the same notebook **two times**, below each other, as two identical cells. Be sure to run a fresh kernel.

```
DynamicModule[{x}, Print[1]; Dynamic@x, Initialization :> Print[2]]
```

Now evaluate the **second cell**. Fine, it returns and prints stuff.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now, without quitting the kernel, **evaluate the first cell**. It crashes *Mathematica*. Every time, and only when the first cell is evaluated. If (after a restart) I only evaluate the first cell, *Mathematica* crashes again.

**How come that the outcome of evaluating two identical cells depends on whether the cell is the last one or not?**

Furthermore, this one causes a crash on its own:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, Dynamic@x, Initialization :> Print[2]]
```

---

*Mathematica* 9.0.1.0 Windows 7 (64-bit), no packages, problem persists after full reboot, suggestion bar is turned off.

Comment: No crash here. works fine. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B05aN.png) please say which platform and version you are using when reporting possible errors. I am on windows 7, 64 bit, V 9.01

Comment: Can't reproduce it in 9.0.1 on Windows 7 x64. The FE code differs substantially between platforms--which one are you on?

Comment: Does not crash (MMA 9.0.1 Win7 64). Although I find it a bit strange that 1 gets printed before 2:)

Comment: @Ajasja You shouldn't: `Initialization` code is only evaluated after the return value of the `DynamicModule` is displayed (see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153/89)).

Comment: Same behaviour for me, W7 32b MMA 9.0.1 [here](http://i.imgur.com/eBXTyRY.png)

Comment: @Öskå Does it also crash on your machine?

Comment: @IstvánZachar [not at all](http://i.imgur.com/7VF8aBM.png), depending one what you mean by crash.

Comment: `Are you saying (looking at your figure) that none of the Print statements get printed on your machine?` They do get printed, I just happened to have changed my preferences to send Print output to the console window. They did go there, I saw the prints on the console.

Comment: Both outputs print fine for me. No crash. OS X V8 and V9

Comment: @IstvánZachar, same story for me with the first `DynamicModule`. Now the second one does crash.

Comment: Well, apparently I'm like the only one with you to have issues. If you got further tests you can ping me in chat if you want to :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tech Support kindly answered and acknowledged the crash:

> The crash is now reproducible after setting the option
>   `CellGrouping -> Manual`.  I have forwarded it to the developers for
>   further investigation. You will be informed when a fix is made
>   available.

You can turn off manual `CellGrouping` with:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, CellGrouping -> Automatic]
```

Also, restarting *Mathematica* in clean mode resets everything including cell grouping behaviour to defaults and the two cells behave normally. The documentation states:

> `mathematica.exe -clean`: ignore stored caches and rebuild the front end preferences file

(It also seems like from the documentation that this is a Mac-only option, but it also applies to Win.)